# How can I find my lost dog in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As the title says, I have lost my wolf named Grim in my world.
I really want to find it. Also, it was spawned with the invulnerable tag
and I don't want to spawn another one.

Any help will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can teleport to a named entity, or teleport a named entity to you:

Teleport (go) to:

```
/tp @p @e[name=Grim]
```

Summon (teleport to you):

```
/tp @e[name=Grim] @p
```