# I lost my dog on Minecraft, How can I get him back?

Tags: minecraft-commands

As I mentioned above my wolf Buddy Jr Jr (yes I know his name should be Buddy the third) is lost and I really want him back, if anybody knows what to do please let me know it would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you specify which Minecraft version you're playing?

Comment: In case of the Java Edition, does this answer your question? [How can I find my lost dog in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263680/how-can-i-find-my-lost-dog-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

On Bedrock Edition you could do a teleport command to teleport all wolves in loaded chunks to you. If I can recall correctly, the command is `/tp @e [type=wolf] @s`.

I can't confirm if this command is the same for Java Edition, but it could be possible that they're the same.

I'd recommend doing the command in a safe, medium/large enclosed room, as in my experience the teleported mobs often launch themselves outward from their starting point in all directions in order to avoid entity cramming.

Comment: I'd also recommend making a world backup before doing the teleportation command, as typing the command wrong sometimes teleports every mob to you instead, and if a creeper's anywhere in the loaded chunks, they automatically explode when teleported with /tp @e commands, which would put all the other mobs, and your player in danger.

Comment: I can confirm the command is the same for Java Edition.

Answer (score 0):

On Java Edition, the command `/tp @e[type=Wolf] @p` should work, however, be aware that this will only work if your dog is in a loaded chunk, which is usually 8 chunks around you

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Make sure to answer the question. :D